# Can't trigger a click event on "a" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to trigger a click event on an `<a>` element, but nothing happens. I want that the link included on href open a new tab.

I've used:

```
$("#tables a").eq(0).click();
```

Anybody knows why is not working?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your HTML.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you just trying to follow the link? Perhaps visit some of the ***Related*** questions to the right.

Comment: Why not working with simple javascript?    <a onclick="event ();" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click()` will trigger the event, but not actually click the link. The closest you can get is `window.open`:

```
window.open($('#tables a').get(0).href);
```

Or, to open it in the same page:

```
window.location.href = $('#tables a').get(0).href;
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, turns out .click has always existed (keanu-whoa). For posterity's sake:

> .click is not a method on DOMElement (which is what $(...)[0] will
>   be).
>
> ```
> $("#tables a").first().click();
> ```
>
> There's also .eq() if you need something other than the first link.
>
> API reference:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: From your docs link: *"Inherits methods from its parent, [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLElement)..."* Follow the `HTMLElement` link, and you'll see there's a `.click()` method. Either way, OP's jQuery code would trigger all the handlers. Adding `.first()` wouldn't fix it.

Comment: Well whaddayaknow, TIL. Thanks!